# Solving quadratic inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

I have a quadratic inequality I am halfway through solving but cannot quite figure out the concept.
$$3+\frac{4-x}x>0$$
I so far understand that without knowing whether x is positive, I would need to square it, but I do not know what comes next.

Comment: It is not a quadratic inequality. Just take L.C.M and see the sign change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$3+\frac{4-x}{x} >0$$

$$\frac{3x+4-x}{x} >0$$

$$\frac{2x+4}{x} >0$$

Divide both sides by $2$

$$\frac{x+2}{x} >0$$

Now use **wavy curve** method

$-\infty+++++ (-2)-----(0)++++++ \infty$

As we want L.H.S. to be positive, hence we get

$x \in (-\infty, -2) \cup (0, \infty)$

**Edit 1**

Let me explain you how I decided the signs.

When $x>0$, then $x+2>0$ and $x>0$, hence $\frac{x+2}{x}$ will be positive.

Again when $x<-2$, then $x+2<0$ and $x<0$, hence $\frac{x+2}{x}$ will be positive.

When $-2<x<0$, then $x+2>0$ but $x<0$, hence $\frac{x+2}{x}$ will be negative.

That is how I decided the sign.

Comment: How did you figure out the signs in the solution?

Comment: By plugging in random numbers, that is, pick a number from each region and see what the sign of the output is. For example, plugging in x=-3 gives a positive  output, x=-1 gives a negative output and x=1 gives a positive. To solve inequalities in general, this method is really the best of the methods posted.

Comment: @imranfat so if the output is 0, does it mean its bigger/smaller and equal?

Comment: @RogerHo I have edited the question. Check it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a quadratic inequality but rather a reciprocal one, as we can shuffle the left-hand side a little:
$$3+\frac{4-x}x>0$$
$$3+\frac4x-1>0^*$$
$$2+\frac4x>0$$
$$\frac4x>-2$$
$$\frac1x>-\frac12$$
$$x<-2\text{ or }x>0$$
*Because we take $\frac xx=1$, we must exclude the $x=0$ case because it results in an indeterminate form.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really get how you got from the last step to having the roots? Would you mind explaining?

Comment: It comes from plotting the graph of $\frac1x$. Alternatively we can split the inequality into positive and negative cases and consider each separately; for positive _x_ it always holds, hence $x>0$, while for negative _x_ it only holds for $x<-2$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find all Solutions to $3 + \frac{4-x}{x} >0$.

At first, we have to make a distinction between (i) $x>0$ and (ii) $x<0$. Since $x=0$ is not possible, all possible values of $x$ are covered by this distinction.

(i) We multiply the inequality by $x$. Since $x$ is positive, the ">" remains a ">":

$$3x + 4 - x > 0 \Longleftrightarrow 2x > -4 \Longleftrightarrow x>-2.$$

(ii) We multiply the inequality by $x$. Since $x$ is negative, this time the ">" changes to a "<":

$$3x + 4 - x < 0 \Longleftrightarrow 2x < -4 \Longleftrightarrow x<-2.$$

Conclusion: The set "L" of all solutions can be written as the Union

$$L = \{x>0, x>-2\} \cup \{x<0,x<-2\} = \{x>0\} \cup \{x<-2\} = (-\infty,-2) \cup (0, \infty).$$

Comment: may I ask how you got from (ii) x<-2 to 0?

Comment: In the case (ii), we assume that x<0. That's the reason why we get the "<" - we multiply with a negative number. Now I solve this easier inequality and receive $x<-2$. So possible solutions of case (ii) have to be smaller than 0 and smaller than -2. That means, that they have to be smaller than -2 at all. That's how we get $(-\infty,-2) in the solution set.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following

> $\frac{A}{B}>0$ and $B\not=0$ if and only if $AB>0$.

It holds for the other remaining inequality signs ($<$, $\leq$, etc). Trivially, it also holds for $=$.

So after obtaining the following,

$$\frac{x+2}{x}>0$$

where $x\not=0$, we can rewrite it as

$$x(x+2)>0$$

As the other answer called it as "wavy curve" method, draw a number line with the zeros of $x(x+2)$ and determine the sign of $x(x+2)$ at each interval.

Finally select the intervals with positive signs (because of $>$ in $\frac{x+2}{x}>0$).

Thus the solution is

$$x<-2\text{ or }x>0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I suppose that your inequality is:
$$
3+\frac{4-x}{x}>0
$$
that, for $x\ne 0$ becomes

$$
\frac{2x+4}{x}>0
$$

now note that a fraction is positive if the numerator and the denominator have the same sign.

---

The inequality is equivalent to the two  systems:

$$
\begin{cases}
2x+4>0\\
x>0
\end{cases}
\quad \mbox{or} \quad
\begin{cases}
2x+4<0\\
x<0
\end{cases}
$$
with solution:

$x<-2$ or $x>0$

Comment: And you need to consider the cases $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately, resulting in two conditions/ranges on $x$.

Comment: so after that I would take 2 out of the numerator so leaves $2(x+2)/x$, then I would get $x > 0$ and $x > -2$? I'm not sure if I got the signs correct

Comment: I've added to my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, I understand it more, but how do you determine both of the systems and how would you extrapolate the solutions from the two systems?